# Is there such thing as HTML tab alignment?

Tags: html, layout, text

It is nice in word processors to create short-term column layouts with documents by using tab key with the defined anchors across the top instead of using tables because you can run overlaps like this.

```
L                                      R
column a row 1          column a row two
this is the first column!   on the right
```

This allows for overlap, or naturally spanning columns without the need for so much structure. Great when you don't need borders.

Can this layout be done in HTML? I know a tabbed layout can be accomplished on a webpage, what I don't know is if you can set the column locations like you can in StarOffice/LibreOffice/OpenOffice Text or in Microsoft Word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using div tags with the float: left and float: right styles, you can achieve this type of structure.